# Install .appxbundle on Windows 10 Home edition

Tags: windows-10, xamarin.uwp

I created a Xamarin UWP app, which was successfully installed in my Windows laptop using App Installer.

Now, I am trying to install it into a windows tab, which has Windows 10 Home Edition.

[image]

**Edit** : My aim is to run .appxbundle app on Windows 10 tablet Home edition. I am not able to install App Installer in the tab. The "Free" button is disabled. What could be the problem?
Could it be because it shows that "this application is currently only available for desktop PCs". It is a Windows tablet, it looks same as windows desktop.

**Edit 2** : I tried to install .AppxBundle using Powershell : https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-appx-files-windows-10/

I gives an error :
`Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFD, A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied.
Unspecified error
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] d5a9e1f9-eb6c-0001-f6e5-a9d56cebd301 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID d5a9e1f9-eb6c-0001-f6e5-a9d56cebd301
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage .\Appinstaller.AppxBundle
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\virtuz...ller.AppxBundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand`

**Note** : The usual Windows system contains Windows 10 Pro, but the tablet contains Windows 10 Home edition. ***Is it something to do with the Window edition*** ?

**Edit 3** : @maginandre1981, My machine only has 'Use developer features' option, no 'Enable Device Portal' option is present.[image]

Here is the basic configuration of the windows tablet
[image]

Comment: Please see [ask]. Why are you unable to do what this? Please update the question with an [edit] and show error messages etc.  Screen caps are not generally useful for this sort of thing. Also, what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it describes the problem a bit more clearly.

Comment: here is the appx I have: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8Slf4l6pnLPq8blRzW-A use [device portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-desktop#set-up-device-portal-on-windows-desktop) to install the appx and now you should be able to install the appxbundle

Comment: This seems like something that good be answered by some research. What have you discovered? You have an idea of the cause it looks like. Why not dig into that?

Comment: I have edited the question with "Edit 2".

Comment: @magicandre1981, In tablet Windows 10 Home edition, In the 'For developers' menu, there is only 'Use developer features' option, no 'Enable Device Portal' option is present. Then I tried to install your link for AppInstaller, using PowerShell. I have mentioned the error in the 'Edit 2' section of the question.

Comment: on my Win10 home I see the option. The error means you miss a dependency . so install the VC14 runtime appx files via Powershell: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8SloFnfMaNzH9hLlkcrg , https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8SloFm5bVGL2SFenvnWw

Comment: The App Installer is only supported by the PC device running on Windows 10, 1607 or later. Accoding to the error code, it indicates  a required prerequisite   is not satisfied.  You might refer to this doc to check the UWP package sideloading [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10).

Comment: @magicandre1981, I have already installed vc14 runtime appx files. Also, please check the 'Edit 3' section of the question.

Comment: I posted an answer. you use an old Windows 10 version. update to the version 1709 or 1803.

Comment: have you done the update to the latest Win10 versions? can you install the app installer app and the bundle files?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I don't have that machine available as for now. I'll update you, when I try this.

Comment: have you made the update to 1803? does "app installer" install the appx now?

Comment: Instead of updating the windows version, I got the machine having app installer already installed. So, I am able to install appx files now.

Comment: and this version is running a recent Windows 10 build (1709/1803)?

Answer (score 0):

From the picture in edit 3 I assume that you use an old Windows 10 Build (TH1 - Build 10240 or TH2 Build 10586).

Update to [Windows 10 v1709/1803 by downloading the ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), double click the ISO to mount it into a virtual DVD drive, run `setup.exe` from the DVD

[image]

and [select keep apps & data](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-version-1803-spring/617a37da-8fc0-4f33-a3eb-59fe9082f925?auth=1)

[image]

Now you see both device portal and the App Installer app will be also downloadable.